# Virtuemart login page - missing info

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, virtuemart

I am running Virtuemart 1.1.9 & Joomla 1.5.25.

When users click on register, they are only prompted for Name, Username, email, password, verify password.  What do I have to change to get a registration page similar to [this](http://extensions.virtuemart.net/my-account)??

My site is [ssgiorder.com](http://ssgiorder.com).

AHIA,
LarryR.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the Home menu option permissions was set to Registered.  Once this was changed back to Public, it worked correctly....

Answer (score 0):

From the VM admin,you can configure the custom fields, and whether or not they appear, as well as whether or not they are required.

Comment: I have enabled every filed in VM->Admin->Manage User Fields...no luck  my site it ssgiprder.com

Comment: Are you sure that "When users click on register", it's going to VM's shop.registration, and not the default joomla registration?

Comment: Just checked your page, and it seems to be okay now.  What was the issue?